# Haisu: Pixel Perfect

Tags: mazes, grid-deduction

HAISU is a portmanteau of three Japanese words - 'hairu', to enter, 'su', number, and 'hausu', an English borrow word meaning house, of course.
Together, we get a meaning of 'enter number house', which I have roughly translated to English as 'Room Count'.

The rules are simple - draw a path from the O to the X, passing through every cell in the grid exactly once. The grid is divided into several rooms. When your path passes over a cell with the big number N, it must be the Nth time you have entered the room. If a room has a small number m in the top left corner, you must enter that room a total of m times. An example Haisu puzzle and its unique solution are shown below.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this example puzzle clarifies the rules.

My previous Haisus have been over-complicated and/or difficult, so here is a puzzle which is MUCH more moderate in difficulty!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the unique solution:

> [image]

and here's one way to get there, all steps being forced so that the outcome is known to be unique. Let's begin with the 3-visit region near the top left. There's only one way to arrange that.

> [image]

And now the regions to its left are straightforward.

> [image]

Let's add the obvious things in the corners, which we should really have done first on autopilot.

> [image]

Now we can fill in the centre-left region:

> [image]

The path can't cross the north and west boundaries of the central region for fear of giving too many visits to the L-shape above it.

> [image]

Thinking about that region at top centre, we have to do this for fear of too many visits to adjacent regions:

> [image]

Count entrances and exits for the 2-visit L-shape near the middle:

> [image]

If we join the upper two bits of path in that region near the bottom left, they'll end up being part of a loop that doesn't visit every square. So don't do that:

> [image]

We can't enter the single-visit region near top right from the left, because that would make the top-right region impossible, so:

> [image]

There's very little flexibility at top right and we fairly quickly find we have to do this:

> [image]

Counting entrances and exits of the bottom area, we must have this:

> [image]

leading quickly here:

> [image]

There's only one way to handle the cell to the right of the start, and then we can count entrances and exits of the 3-visit L-shaped region:

> [image]

Now there's only one way to fill in that narrow corridor:

> [image]

and all that remains is the earliest portion of the path:

> [image]

Comment: You little ninja... oh well.

Comment: @stackreader You've still got a chance with the Rose puzzle!

Comment: Sorry! If I'd known someone else was working on it I'd have been happy to leave it alone.

Comment: Don't feel bad, you won fare and square.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution

Only way to get 2 entrances in a 2X2 square.

> [image]

The 2 lines must connect so that only 1 entrance is done in the room bellow.

> [image]

Once again, Only way to get 2 entrances in a 2X2 square.

> [image]

Logical deductions to only allow 2 entrances in the big room.

> [image]

The 2 red dots must connect somewhere or else the room to the right will be impossible to solve in just 1 entrance. From there, we can do further logical deductions.

> [image]

Only possible way to hit the 2 on the second entrance without forcing more then 1 entry on the room to the left.

> [image]

Only way to enter 3 times in the lower left room.

> [image]

The rest just comes together on its own.

> [image]